# Why my i18n doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, devise

locales/devise.zh-CN.yml

application.rb

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.default_locale = "zh-CN"
I18n.locale = 'zh-CN'
```

And I restart the server,but it doesn't work?!

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what exactly does not work? What exactly are you trying, what output are you expecting, what is the actual output/behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I believe locales should only have the main language (in your case `zh`) without the region.

Rename your file `locales/devise.zh.yml` and set your locale with `I18n.locale = 'zh'`

Also make sure your locale file starts with `zh:`, i.e.:

```
zh:
  hello: "Hello world localized"
```

Comment: are you sure? I'm just using 'zh-CN.yml' and it's totally fine.